# Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4 indent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

** Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4  indent**

```
 export default [
{
    name: 'abc',
    breed: 'afghan hound',
    gender: 'male',
    age: 9,
    color: 'gray',
    weight: 68,
    location: 'threed',
    notes: 'super friendly'
}
```

]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you have eslint or something enabled? Change rules to allow 4, or change file to be 2 spaces. Or disable eslint/other static code analysis

Comment: i am new in vue js i don't know about eslint

Comment: People would need more details to help you then, such as your project structure, what packages you've included - if you've followed a tutorial then possibly a link to it. But changing your IDE configuration to use 2 spaces and reformatting the code should get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

For simple indentation with Vue, I recommend you use the Prettier.

The default indentation of Prettier is 2 spaces, but you can change this. See this option: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width

The Prettier have integration with many editors: https://prettier.io/docs/en/editors.html

Prettier is a great tool.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people.

Comment: i think he forgot how to turn the pc back on